# where to find MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

how to get MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll Actually I produced code from Mygeneration utility and it requires this dll file. I find on many places but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MyGeneration presents dOOdads, an
>   elegant .NET architecture available in
>   C# and VB.NET and capable of
>   supporting any .NET managed data
>   provider. Currently dOOdads are
>   available for Microsoft SQL, Oracle,
>   Firebird, Access, PostgreSQL, VistaDB,
>   SQLite, and MySQL
>
> (The dOOdads Architecture is no longer
>   being maintained)

http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/dOOdads/Overview/tabid/63/Default.aspx

http://download.cnet.com/MyGeneration/3000-10250_4-10685426.html?tag=lst-0-1

Comment: BUt my question is that from where I can get MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll I have generated the code from MyGeneration tool but problem is it requires MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll ans there is no MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this too.  You have to build it yourself.  Instructions can be found at "[Introduction to myGeneration and dOOdads](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-65-Introduction%20to%20myGeneration%20and%20dOOdads)".

Good luck!